# jQuery .data(key) not retrieving updated .data(key, value) data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already know that jQuery.data() is not the same that .attr(), and it doesn't update the actual HTML, but I'm using .data(key, value) and then I can't retrieve the updated changes with .data(key), which is weird because I've done that A LOT in the past. After a few hours with this, I am out of ideas.

At first I was stringifying and parseing the object to JSON but then I read that Jquery automagically does that, so it was unnecessary and potentially damaging.

### HTML:

```
<div id="invitationsLooper" class="looper slide" data-looperdata="{}">     
(...stuff)
    <div id="platform_selector"> </div>
</div>
```

### JS:

```
<script>
 var $looper = jQuery("#invitationsLooper");
 $looper.data("looperdata",{id:"invitationsLooper"});
 console.log("Initializing looperdata: "+$looper.data("looperdata"));

  $looper.on("platform_reset", function (event) {
        //var $looper = jQuery("#invitationsLooper");

        console.log("[Platform reset] event");
        console.log($looper);
        console.log($looper.data("looperdata"));
        var looperdataobject = $looper.data("looperdata");
        console.log(looperdataobject);

        looperdataobject.idplatform = null;
        $looper.data("looperdata", looperdataobject);
        console.log(looperdataobject);
    });

 </script>
```

The event is launched on click by this line in another script:

```
<script>
    jQuery("#platform_selector").trigger("platform_reset");
</script>
```

### Firebug console output:

> Initializing looperdata: [object Object]
>
> -->platfom_reset event fired
>
> [Platform reset] event
>
> Object[div#invitationsLooper.looper.slide]
>
> null
>
> null
>
> TypeError: null has no properties looperdataobject.idplatform = null;

Comment: Is the `$looper` variable used/changed between the time it is declared and the time the `platform_reset` event is fired? I would suggest you use `$(this)` within the event handler to access the object that raised the event instead.

Comment: `$looper.data("looperdata",{id:"invitationsLooper"});` does this work? I guess the second parameter needs to be string or integer.

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7uz8a2z9/1/

Comment: @Doodlebunch that will work fine. Because the `data` values are stored in an object you can use any type you like, not just a string.

Comment: Created a JSFiddle and it worked fine for me, are you sure that you have no other elements with id invitationsLooper or are overwritting it anywhere else?

Comment: @Doodlebunch $looper.data("looperdata",{id:"invitationsLooper"}); does work, that's why you can read [object Object] in the console (in the actual console is clicable and you can see the content). Anyways, when I tried converting it to JSON string first, I had the same issue later on.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nope, $looper is never touched in between. I tried using it global, var $looper = jQuery(this); and var $looper = jQuery('#invitationsLooper'); Same result, always. (As you can see in the "Object[div#invitationsLooper.looper.slide]" console line, the object is found)

Thanks everyone for you answers.

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz But in your platform_reset-Event looperdataobject is null, is it possible that `platform_reset` resets the loopers data attribute?

Comment: @Doodlebunch no, I think it's not possible. The "platform_reset" event is triggered() by a child asking the container to reset his platform data and then add the new selected data via "platfom_selected" event (next step, not relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, though it was very specific. At the beginning of the script I made initialized the [looper.js library](http://rygine.com/projects/looper.js/docs/) like this:

```
jQuery('.looper').looper({interval: false})
```

I knew that this call modified the DOM, but I assumed that if all .data() changes were made AFTER that call it would be safe. **It isn't.** It must have some delayed modification (maybe a window.ready call) because if I fired the event through code, it worked, but when I made it through click (after everything was loaded), it didnt.

I commented that line and everything went smooth. Extra caution must be taken, I assume.

**Sorry for your time. I really appreciated your help.**

PS: I'm pretty new to Stack Overflow, so I don't know if I should delete or rename the question. Let me know, please.